# How to create a pdf file on button click in android?

Tags: android, forms, pdf

I have 8 edittext fields in my android app, I enter the data manually into the same and at the end of the field there is so called "Save" button

What I want is when I click on the save button, a pdf file should be generated with all the values that I have filled in the edittext. Any help is appreciated.. Thanks

Comment: In android iText library is availble for creating pdf.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [itext7](https://github.com/itext/itext7) library to do just that. But do look at their licensing as they mention you may need to buy license as soon as you are using it for commercial purpose.

I actually used [itext5](https://github.com/itext/itextpdf) which seems deprecated now. But the code should not be much different.

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mContentEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty()){
                mContentEditText.setError("Body is empty");
                mContentEditText.requestFocus();
                return;
            }
            try {
                createPdfWrapper();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (DocumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

The `createPdfWrapper()` method definition is as follows:

```
private void createPdfWrapper() throws FileNotFoundException,DocumentException{

    int hasWriteStoragePermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (hasWriteStoragePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS)) {
                showMessageOKCancel("You need to allow access to Storage",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                                    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                                            REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                return;
            }

            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
        }
        return;
    }else {
        createPdf();
    }
```

As you can see you will also need WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission which should be declared in `AndroidManifest.xml` .

The permission result can be handled in `onRequestPermissionsResult` as:

```
 @Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS:
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // Permission Granted
                try {
                    createPdfWrapper();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (DocumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                // Permission Denied
                Toast.makeText(this, "WRITE_EXTERNAL Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
            }
            break;
        default:
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

The other functions used here have the following definitions:

```
private void showMessageOKCancel(String message, DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
            .create()
            .show();
}

private void createPdf() throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException {

    File docsFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Documents");
    if (!docsFolder.exists()) {
        docsFolder.mkdir();
        Log.i(TAG, "Created a new directory for PDF");
    }

    pdfFile = new File(docsFolder.getAbsolutePath(),"HelloWorld.pdf");
    OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(pdfFile);
    Document document = new Document();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, output);
    document.open();
    document.add(new Paragraph(mContentEditText.getText().toString()));

    document.close();
    previewPdf();

}

private void previewPdf() {

    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    testIntent.setType("application/pdf");
    List list = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(testIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    if (list.size() > 0) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        //Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile); //This did not work, SO created a GenericFileProvider, register in xml, created provider_paths.xml

        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(),
                getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
                        + ".my.package.name.provider", pdfFile);
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");

        startActivity(intent);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this,"Download a PDF Viewer to see the generated PDF",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

**The main thing to look for here is the `createPdf()` method** This is where I have created a PDF file with text from my `EditText`.

If you wish to have a look at the full code that I did you can visit [my github respository](https://github.com/pfieffer/PDFCreate/tree/iTextLibrary) here.

Good Luck!!!

Comment: hi ravi..i visited your github repository for the reference..when i cloned it in my android studio and built the apk..the only thing i found is Simple "hello world" Text..Nothing else..if you have another reference github repository you can share..thanks

Comment: hey akshay, the `master` branch of that repo has only a simple helloworld project. The actual code is in branch `iTextLibrary`. To clone that branch, please use `git clone -b iTextLibrary https://github.com/pfieffer/PDFCreate.git`. Once cloned you may also need to checkout to that branch: `git checkout iTextLibrary`

Comment: Thanks ravi..i followed your steps and now the UI is visible to me..i filled the edit text and clicked on create pdf button..automatically my "pdf Viewer" app gets open but no content is shown in that whatever i have filled in edittext..it simply shows black screen..Can you help me out with this?

Comment: `np.com.ravi.pdfcreate D/Surface: Surface::disconnect(this=0x748986f000,api=1)
2019-08-14 12:50:22.009 30398-30417/np.com.ravi.pdfcreate D/OpenGLRenderer: ~CanvasContext() 0x746e882180
2019-08-14 12:50:22.011 30398-30417/np.com.ravi.pdfcreate D/OpenGLRenderer: ~CanvasContext() 0x746e9b3b80`   You can refer this for more info..My debug screen

Comment: Which OS version are you testing on? You may need to use `FileProvider`: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider
And do check for the document from your Device Explorer in AndroidStudio.
As for the error log, is it crashing or is it just a warning?